# Nest StackNavigator in a custom BottomTabNavigator, React Navigation V>2

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a project configured with `React Navigation` V1. when i update `React Navigation` to version 2, tab icons is disappears... this is the routing structure:

```
public static Routes = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: { screen: Splash },
    EditProfile: { screen: EditProfile },
    Main: {
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
            Search: {
                screen: createStackNavigator({
                    Home: { screen: Home },
                    DoctorList: { screen: DoctorList },
                }, stackConfig('Home')
                )
            },
            Bookmark: {
                screen: createStackNavigator({
                    BookmarkList: { screen: BookmarkList },
                }, stackConfig('BookmarkList')
                )
            },
            User: {
                screen: createStackNavigator({
                    Profile: { screen: Profile },
                }, stackConfig('Profile')
                )
            },
        }, tabConfig('Search'))
    }
}, stackConfig('Splash')
)


let stackConfig = (initialRouteName: any): any => {
    return {
        initialRouteName: initialRouteName,
        headerMode: 'none',
        cardStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
    }
}

let tabConfig = (initialRouteName: any): any => {
    return {
        initialRouteName: initialRouteName,
        tabBarComponent: TabBarComponent,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarOptions: {
            labelStyle: {
                fontFamily: Utility.font,
                fontSize: Platform.OS !== 'ios' ? 9 : 11,
                margin: 0,
            },
            activeTintColor: '#2e9699',
            inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            showIcon: true,
            showLabel: true,
            indicatorStyle: {
                backgroundColor: 'red',
            },
            style: {
                zIndex: 1,
                backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                height: 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

[image]

When i remove StackNavigator from a tab ( ex: `User: Profile` ), icon will appears correctly. i think a difference between V1 and V2 causes this but i don't know it.

For example, `Profile.tsx` is like this:

```
export default class Profile extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
            <Icon name="md-person" size={27} color={focused ? colors.green : colors.black} />
        )
    };
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At V2, navigation options can only be configured its direct parent. **Example**: your Profile screen can only configure for its parent, stacknavigator. Your profile screen cannot set the **createBottomTabNavigator options** without shuffling navigators

If you want to configure the **createBottomTabNavigator options**, you can do as shown in following:

```
public static Routes = createStackNavigator({
    Splash: { screen: Splash },
    EditProfile: { screen: EditProfile },
    Main: {
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
            Search: {screen: HomeStack},
            Bookmark: {screen: BookmarkStack},
            User: {screen:UserStack},
        }, tabConfig('Search'))
    }
}, stackConfig('Splash')
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    tabBarLabel: "Explore",
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
         <Icon name="md-person" size={27} color={focused ? colors.green : colors.black} />
    )
  };
};

BookmarkStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    tabBarLabel: "Explore",
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
         <Icon name="md-bookmark" size={27} color={focused ? colors.green : colors.black} />
    )
  };
};

UserStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    tabBarLabel: "Explore",
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => (
         <Icon name="md-user" size={27} color={focused ? colors.green : colors.black} />
    )
  };
};
```

I hope it will work for you. PS : I didn't test my code.